# Confused by different behavior of lambda function

Tags: python-3.7

```
def foo():
    lst = []
    for i in range(4):
        lst.append(lambda: i)
        print(lst[i]())
    print([f() for f in lst])
foo()
```

**this is the output for above code**

```
0
1
2
3
[3, 3, 3, 3]
```

why the lst inside the for loop is printing `[0,4)` and lst outside the for loop is printing `[3,3,3,3]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do (lambda) function closures capture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture)

Comment: in a nutshell: because the lambda refers to the value of the variable `i` _when the lambda is called_, and after the loop this value is `3`

Comment: Best explanation [Late-binding closures](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures)